# How is the Joomla Issue Tracker documentation generated?

Tags: joomla-api, documentation

Can anyone here share some light on how these Joomla docs were made

http://issues.joomla.org/documentation/

I know that the docs are pulled from github MD files but 
if someone could explain the process since I am not finding exact how to's.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think they are using the Github library scripts that come packaged with Joomla, which you will find under `root/libraries/joomla/github`. A jQuery Tree plugin is also being used along with some Ajax which loads the subdirectories/files upon clicking a category.

Comment: @Lodder It's using the framework - not the CMS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The documentation is stored** in our [JIssues GitHub repo](https://github.com/joomla/jissues) in Markdown format for easy processing and contributing.

**To display the docs on site**, we use a [command line script](https://github.com/joomla/jissues/blob/master/cli/Application/Command/Make/Docu.php) which scans the folder, parses the Markdown document into HTML via the GitHub API, and the rendering is stored into the database.

Comment: Thnx Michael. can you point me to where in DB the rendering is stored?

Comment: That would be in the articles table - https://github.com/joomla/jissues/blob/master/etc/mysql.sql#L289

Answer (score 5):

So the JIssues tracker uses the Joomla Framework - so some of the github dependencies are bundled in via composer from https://github.com/joomla-framework/github-api

The specific code from the md files here https://github.com/joomla/jissues/tree/master/Documentation

The code that grabs them for rendering is here: https://github.com/joomla/jissues/tree/master/src/App/Support (the file tree with the jQuery tree plugin is in the controller Filetree.php etc.)

And finally the rendering is in a twig template found here: https://github.com/joomla/jissues/blob/master/templates/support/documentation.index.twig