# Is there an extension/script that could pull html pages as articles in to Joomla?

Tags: cms

I am working on centralized documents system for our Joomla demos  and before I go all crazy with plugins/extensions/modules creation I would like to ask you for some guidance.

Currently we have have about 15 articles inside the demo.

**examples;**

http://joomlatemplates.youjoomla.info/eximium/index.php/shortcodes
http://joomlatemplates.youjoomla.info/eximium/index.php/pages/content-views

Since out templates volume is always increasing keeping up demo docs fresh and up to date has become an issue.

I have currently written all those articles in plain html format.
Does anyone know a simple way to pull these inside Joomla?

The idea is to keep them all on our framework website and when user visits the demo the html pages are pulled from our framework site in to Joomla. This way we can always update one set of files instead over 100+ demos.

The issue is that those pages should be processed trough Joomla if possible as Joomla articles.

I have also looked in to this [How is the Joomla Issue Tracker documentation generated?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-is-the-joomla-issue-tracker-documentation-generated)

but to be completely honest I do not know where to begin.

So if you could explain ( or have a working example ) how I can port simple html page in to Joomla article that is always updatable from the source it would be great.

Thank you!

**Update:**

**Since we are using shortcodes I am busting on one that would do what I need, pull html in to article via shortcode. If anyone knows better way please advise.**

**Update:
I ended up making a framework shortcode that works as explained above**
Here is the demo
http://yjsimplegrid.com/shortcodes/parse-page.html

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to load articles from external sources is via **RSS Feeds**.

There are several proven extensions at JED that already implement a RSS Article Grabber: http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=rss+grabber

Comment: That was my first thought, using News feeds but full article needs to be processed because of shortcodes, example , http://joomlatemplates.youjoomla.info/eximium/index.php/shortcodes/112-icons

Comment: Some extensions allow to post-process articles. But, it's very specific, how to insert your icons.

Comment: I found a way that is working for us. Will post a solution once done. Still testing.

Comment: Any solution to this?